# Formattedtextfield and DateTime in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, datetime, jformattedtextfield

How can i automatically write current system date as `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"` to formatted text field after program is launched in JAVA?

Actually i have two formatted text field. One of must be shown current system date - `5 Min`  second must be shown current system date after program is launched.

When i run this program Jpanel comes. Ihave these 2 formattedtextfield in this panel.

Left one: must be show current system date - 5min (2013-12-22 21:00:00.000)

Right one: must be show current system date (2013-12-22 21:05:00.000)

How can i code it for automaticly appear this values to fields?

P.S: sorry i dont attach image because i dont have 10 rep yet :(

Comment: Your question is unclear. Further explain _"5 Min second must be shown current system date after program is launched."_ and _"And these formatted text fields can be editable but only date and time changing._". And show us some code of what you have attempted.

Comment: I have just edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html?is-external=true) the set the text of the textfield with the current time

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateString = formatter.format(date);
    formatText = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("####-##-## ##:##:##"));
    formatText.setColumns(20);
    formatText.setText(dateString);
```

If you need to get the date value of the input text, just parse it.

```
   Date date;
   try {
       date = formatter.parse(formatText.getText());
   } catch (ParseException ex) {
       ...
   }
```

And to set the field editable with the desired format, you can use a [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html). See my example. It runs

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class MaskFormatterTest1 extends JPanel {

    private JFormattedTextField formatText;

    public MaskFormatterTest1() {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String dateString = formatter.format(date);
        formatText = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("####-##-## ##:##:##"));
        formatText.setColumns(20);
        formatText.setText(dateString);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Enter Date and Time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(formatText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;
        try {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
            System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return formatter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("MaskFormatter example");
                frame.add(new MaskFormatterTest1());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use HH, not hh in SimpleDateFormat-pattern (hour from 0 to 23).

Comment: Thanks to you peeskillet. I already take some codes in your code table.

Comment: Ah i am new in stackoverflow. So i dont know general deportments yet sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

For setting the current system date you need:

```
JFormattedTextField ftf = ...;
ftf.setValue(new Date());
```

For setting the right format you need a DefaultFormatterFactory and the DateFormatter:

```
DateFormatter df = new DateFormatter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(); // other ctors possible
factory.setDefaultFormatter(df); // here simple default solution
ftf.setFormatterFactory(factory);
```

Note: You should read the javadoc. There are several variations for edit and display mode. So in your scenario you need two fields (and therefore two dates):

```
JFormattedTextField ftfLeft = ...; // create and set the format
JFormattedTextField ftfRight = ...; // create and set the format
Date now = new Date();
Date nowMinusFiveSeconds = new Date(now.getTime() - 5 *1000);
ftfLeft.setValue(nowMinusFiveSeconds);
ftfRight.setValue(now);
```

Comment: Thanks Meno, i can try these codes in Netbeans. I am confused sometimes because Netbeans has Designer Gui as you know. I must entegration these codes to right place first.

Comment: In your question it is not clear if you mean 5 seconds or five minutes. I have now posted an example code for the case in seconds. For minutes you need to multiply the factor 5 by 60.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution Meno.